# Looking for the source that connects the days of the week to the sefirot

Tags: sources-mekorot, calendar, mysticism-kabbalah, months

[image: Luach]

I found a picture of it, but I absolutely cannot find the title. I remember reading about certain months correlating to din, some rachamim, the rest judgment is pending. So, I'm hoping this book has those sources too.

Comment: How about Sefer Yetzirah

Answer (score 2):

This appears in Nahar Shalom (by R. Shalom Sharabi), in the introduction of the "HaMa'avir" brakha, p. 23-24.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 0):

No idea what these things mean but see the Kuzari 4:22 - 4:27

https://www.sefaria.org/Kuzari.4.40?lang=bi

The Kuzari himself despite discussing and explaining it ends off by saying that they aren't important things to know. Which is why I doubt they will be understood even after going through the above.